# Big grid of tiny colored squares causes high CPU usage

Tags: android, android-layout, cpu-usage

I have a method creating a large grid of tiny little colored squares, and I noticed that this has a big impact on CPU usage.

Please note that this method is called only once, and that the problem continues and never ends even when the method has finished. If this method is not executed, cpu usage remains low.

```
// regionLayout is a vertical LinearLayout
// gridHorizontalSize and gridVerticalSize determines the size of the grid

regionLayout.removeAllViews();
regionLayout.setWeightSum(gridVerticalSize);

ImageView cell = null;
LinearLayout row;
int color;

for(int i=0; i<gridVerticalSize; i++) {

    row = new LinearLayout(context);
    row.setWeightSum(gridHorizontalSize);
    regionLayout.addView(row, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 1f));

    for(int j=0; j<gridHorizontalSize; j++) {

        cell = new ImageView(context);

        color = /* color is chosen somehow */

        cell.setBackgroundColor(color);

        row.addView(cell, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f));
    }
}
```

I used two LinearLayout to make a grid because I'm unfamiliar with GridLayout and didn't really know how to set a weightSum for both horizontal and vertical sizes.
I used ImageViews for no particular reason, I just need something I can set a color on.

Grids are usually around 30x30 squares, so that makes 900 little colored squares and I know it's a lot, but there's no way around it, I need to have 900 of them on screen at the same time.

What can I change to have an improvement? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a custom view, not nested Linear Layouts. You've created 900 view objects on one screen. That is a huge performance hit.

I have a grid board view that I made for a project that you can look at to reference 
https://github.com/shmuelr/ConwaysGame/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/shmuelrosansky/conwaysgame/views/Board.java

Comment: Thanks! Your answer guided me to a nice solution!